# Union specific columns from 3 tables with different number of columns

Tags: sql, union

I have 3 tables Table A, B and C

Table A got 40 columns
Table B got 41 columns
Table C got 43 columns

if am unioning 3 specific columns from the 3 tables do I have to match the number of columns in all three?

Comment: Yes you can not do a union without matching all columns.  You can select NULL as COLName for the tables that have less to match the tables with more columns.

Comment: You will need to match column data types as well.

Comment: do the order matters?